# Python Count paragraph

Tags: python, paragraphs

Hello all so i've been tasked to count lines and paragraphs. Counting every line is obviously easy but im stuck on counting the paragraphs. If a paragraph has no character it will give back the number zero and for every paragraph is an increment higher. For example an input file is: [Input](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccqmsuqc85jtqp7/essay1.txt?dl=0) and an Output should come out [Output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/scj6zwxwmml489m/problem2.txt?dl=0)
so my code is:

```
def insert_line_para_nums(infile, outfile):
    f = open(infile, 'r')
    out = open(outfile, 'w')
    linecount = 0
        for i in f:
            paragraphcount = 0
            if '\n' in i:
                linecount += 1
            if len(i) < 2: paragraphcount *= 0
            elif len(i) > 2: paragraphcount = paragraphcount + 1
            out.write('%-4d %4d %s' % (paragraphcount, linecount, i))
    f.close()
    out.close()
```

Comment: Every time you see two newline characters together (separated by whitespace, at the most), you know you've ended the previous paragraph.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget i have thought of that! But no idea how or where to implement it :/

Comment: As  inspectorG4dget suggested, check if a `line == '\n'`, since in your example i see no whitespaces in blank lines. If so, disable that check until you find a `line != '\n'` (that is, non empty line), to avoid consecutive black lines marked as paragraph ends. The rest should be easy.

Comment: full stop . is considered as a line count if we see literally. In that case we have to check differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def insert_line_para_nums(infile, outfile):
    f = open(infile, 'r')
    out = open(outfile, 'w')
    linecount = 0
    paragraphcount = 0
    empty = True
    for i in f:
        if '\n' in i:
            linecount += 1
            if len(i) < 2:
                empty = True
            elif len(i) > 2 and empty is True:
                paragraphcount = paragraphcount + 1
                empty = False
            if empty is True:
                paragraphnumber = 0
            else:
                paragraphnumber = paragraphcount
        out.write('%-4d %4d %s' % (paragraphnumber, linecount, i))
    f.close()
    out.close()
```

Comment: what about the last line of the file? that doesn't get read because that doesnt have a \n character?

Comment: Never mind all you need to do is move the out.write under the if :D

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it, and not the prettiest.

```
import re
f = open('a.txt', 'r')

paragraph = 0

lines = f.readlines()

for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    if not line == '\n':
        m = re.search(r'\w', line)
        str = m.group(0)

    try:
        # if the line is a newline, and the previous line has a str in it, then  
        # count it as a paragraph.
        if line == '\n' and str in lines[idx-1]: 
            paragraph +=1
    except:
        pass

if lines[-1] != '\n': # if the last line is not a new line, count a paragraph.
    paragraph +=1

print paragraph
```